# The absolute value of $ e^{iz} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is $ \vert e^{iz} \vert = e^{-Im(z)} $?

I tried rewriting $z$ as $x +iy$, but I can't derive the equality.

Answer (score 4):

If $z=x+iy$ then $e^{iz}=e^{ix}e^{-y}$, and since $|e^{ix}|=1$ it follows that $|e^{iz}|=e^{-y}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}$You only need to prove that for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, (Why?)
$$ |e^z| = e^{\Re z}
$$
This follows directly from Euler's formula, if $z = x + \mathrm iy$,
$$ |e^z| = |e^x e^{\mathrm iy}| = e^x
$$

Comment: Quick question. Why does $\left|e^x\right|=e^x$?

Comment: @Bell Its been a long time since I answered this question, but it seems like $x$ is real, so $e^x$ is positive.

Answer (score 2):

If $$z=x+iy\\iz=xi+i^2y=-y+ix\\\to 
e^{-y+ix}=x^{-y}.e^{ix}=\\e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)$$ so 
$$|e^{iz}|=|e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)|=|e^{-y}|\cdot~|(\cos x+i\sin x)|=\\e^{-y}.\sqrt{\sin^2x+\cos ^2x}=\\e^{-y}.1\\=e^{-y}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$|e^{iz}|=|e^{i(x+iy)}|=|e^{-y+ix}|=|e^{-y}||e^{ix}|=e^{-y}$$

Because $|e^{ix}|=1$ and $e^{-y}\gt 0$